# android native logging, which header to use?

Tags: android, c, logging, android-ndk

I see there's two different logging API for native applications
one is defined in `<utils/Log.h>` and the other in `<android/log.h>`

**the `<android/log.h>` exports the following api**

```
int __android_log_print(int prio, const char *tag,  const char *fmt, ...)
```

**The `<utils/Log.h>` exports this api:**

```
LOGW() - warning
LOGD() - debug
LOGI() - info
LOGV() - verbose
etc...
```

What is the difference between the two, and when each of these header are used ?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, `utils/Log.h` isn't included with the NDK. That kind of solves the problem for you. `utils/Log.h` is used internally by Android in its native layers (though the macros have changed names to `ALOGE`, `ALOGW` etc IIRC).